# fullcalendar multi-day span of event how (javascript code)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I was wondering on how I can manually code on javascript the getting of the start and end date of an event and having it shown in the calendar with a "span". Just like this:

[the span is from dec 27 (start date) to dec 30 (end date) - pls click link to see the sample image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlvRG.png

from my javascript code, i already can retrieve the start date:

```
dayClick: function(date, event, view) {
        currentDate = date.format();
        // Open modal to add event
        modal({
            // Available buttons when adding
            buttons: {
                add: {
                    id: 'add-event', // Buttons id
                    css: 'btn-success', // Buttons class
                    label: 'Add' // Buttons label
                }
            },
            title: 'Add Event (' + date.format() + ')' // Modal title
        });
    },
```

But, if i were to encode the event manually in javascript, the multi-day event span does work. Event encoded manually in javascript looks like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({


header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
}, events: [
    {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2014-09-15T10:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-17T06:00:00'
    }
] });
```

I was actually wondering on how i could get both the start date and end date dynamically from a form and into the database within the javascript.

Here is my html file (as i am running it on codeigniter, it is saved as a php file (this is the view):

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="crud-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-md" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Start date:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" class="form-control input-md" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">End Date:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="end_date" name="end_date" type="text" class="form-control input-md" />
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="color">Color</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="color" name="color" type="text" class="form-control input-md" readonly="readonly" />
                                <span class="help-block">Click to pick a color</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I wish I could see the HTML. I suppose you are creating the calendar dynamically with PHP or some other server-side language, aren't you? In such case, creating a good HTML markup for your JavaScript can help a lot, for example you could give your span `data-start` and `data-end` attributes to easily retrieve them via JavaScript. There are many options, but unfortunately I have to go now. Someone else will help you with more time for sure, but at least here you have an idea.

Comment: Thank you for responding! the html does not contain much, it just contains the modal for when i click a day or event. The CRUD for the fullcalendar is already fully functional, it's just that i cannot create a span as to which i enter both a start date and the end date. The functionality of the calendar fully relies on the javascript, the crud relies on the controller and model.

Comment: Please add your HTML and PHP code too.

Comment: @DenizB. I have now added the html file :)

Comment: Ok, now I understand. As far as I know, you don't need the form tag if you're going to work with JavaScript. If your plan is to use the information of the "form" and send it to the database and then "reload" the calendar, you can do so with AJAX, no matter what other implementation you are using, it will work if you put them together well. Unfortunately I didn't realize up until now that you meant "fullcalendar" as a jQuery plugin (never heard of it) and now I see you are using codeigniter which I have no experience with, so I might just not be the best person to help you.

Comment: But I am willing to help if I can, you can do amazing things with AJAX and PHP together, so I think you can work it out that way. If it doesn't fit your needs, that I understand. Good luck with your project, I'll be following up!

Comment: @Zeke hi! Again, thank you so much for responding. I'm just a beginner and I really do not know much about ajax but from the sample codes i am seeing i really do think it will be of good use for this problem.

Comment: @Laurel No problem at all, I'm glad I'm being useful. I see, in such case I'd love to help you build some AJAX for your problem. I wish you had enough reputation to be in chats, but since you don't, we can find something else rather than comments to continue our conversation because it might take quite a long time to solve it while having you to understand it. I suggest you hit me up on Twitter and we can talk about this over there. Find it on my profile, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: @Zeke ajax would probably solve my problem. I actually changed and played around with the javascript and html last night. I have researched about ajax, and i have tried it. I am dealing with the url problem right now as i am using codeigniter. I would love for you to help me with this!

Comment: @Laurel fair enough, I have no idea about codeigniter but I'm a fast learner and I know quite a lot about AJAX, so I can help you with the AJAX an you do the codeigniter. Find me on Twitter or send me an email. Also, I really don't know what you mean by "url problem".

Comment: @Zeke I have created another question and it is more detailed than this question, i have actually posted the codes I have as a whole. On this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483071/fetch-event-details-title-start-and-end-from-database-for-fullcalendar

Comment: @Laurel great, I'm going to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like your problem is that the JSON object returned by your URL has unrecognizable data for fullCalendar. So you'll have to fetch events like this:

```
events: base_url+'Calendar/view_tours',
```

And change the columns of your data base from `tour_id` to `id`, `tour_name` to `title`, `start_date` to `start` and `end_date` to `end`. This will create the correct JSON object.