# Fetch event details (title, start and end) from database for fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I have really searched a lot about this, but I still haven't gotten through with my problem. I am creating a calendar (using the plugin fullcalendar and using codeigniter as the backend) that would display a tour and it's specific time span. So, in this case the title of the event would be the tour name, and for the duration of the tour, the start and end dates is to be fetched.

I have already succeeded with the insertion of the data to the database, it's just that the events are not appearing on their respective dates.

These are what I have coded so far:

Controller: Calendar.php

```
function view_tours(){ 
    $this->load->model('Calendar_model');
    $tours = $this->Calendar_model->getTours();
    echo json_encode($tours);
}

function add_tour(){
    $sdate = $this->input->post('start_date'); //start date
    $edate = $this->input->post('end_date'); //end date
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){ //column name in db=>name in form
        $tour = array('tour_name' => $this->input->post('tour_name'), 
            'start_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate)), 
            'end_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate)),
            'slots' => $this->input->post('slots'),
            'rate' => $this->input->post('rate'),);
        $this->Calendar_model->insert_tour($tour);
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
        redirect(base_url().'Calendar');
        echo "error";   
    }
}
```

Model: Calendar_model.php

```
public function getTours(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tours');
    return $query -> result_array();
}
function insert_tour($tour){
        $this->db->insert('tours', $tour); 
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**View: home.php** (This is the html file)

```
<div id="AddModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"> Add a Tour </h4> 
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"> 
                     <?php
                          echo validation_errors();
                     ?>
                     <form class="form-horizontal" id="crud-form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Calendar/add_tour">

                     <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tour_name">Tour Name</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tour_name" name="tour_name"/>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="start_date">Start Date</label>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date"/>
                           </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="end_date">End Date</label>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date"/>
                           </div>
                       </div>


                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="slots">Slots</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slots" name="slots"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rate">Rate</label>
                             <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rate" name="rate"/>
                             </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="color">Color</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                 <input id="color" name="color" type="text" class="form-control input-md" readonly="readonly" />
                                 <span class="help-block">Click to pick a color</span>
                             </div>
                       </div>

                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Tour</button>
                       </form>


                 </div> <!--end of modal body-->
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

***I have recently edited this but this does not work.*** 
 **JS File: main.js**  I have tried fetching data using the $.ajax options but when i do this, the calendar itself does not appear. What is wrong with the code? I am just a beginner with ajax.

```
events: {
    url: base_url+'Calendar/view_tours',
    type: 'POST',
    data{
        title: tour_name,
        start: start_date,
        end: end_date

    },error: function(){
        alert('error in fetching from database!');
    }
}, //end of events
```

I just pasted a snippet of the js. I know that the calendar is "somehow" retrieving data from the database because i can see the events, BUT, it only appears on the current date in real time and shows the current time, for all events added. And i have added a tool tip to see if the tour name (title) is being read, and it is.

Here's what the actual results are: [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsQYV.png)

**Summary of problem:**  Events are not in their respective dates and the time added is on realtime.

Comment: Hello again Laurel! Check with tooltip if the dates are correct too or check on the database. Remember to set `displayEventEnd` to true because in the month view it's set as `false` by default (this will help to see if the plugin is reading the database correctly, maybe the database has some issues). About the title not being shown, I haven't found anything in the API so I really don't know.

Comment: Also, there is a final comma after the events final `}`. Erase it and add a comma after `eventLimit: true`. I hadn't noticed such syntax error up until now. I'm glad I checked.

Comment: Hi @Zeke I'll try your suggestions now! i hope it works! About the comma, it's actually supposed to be there as there are following codes for the tooltips :)

Comment: @zeke I have set the displayEventEnd to true. And i checked with tooltip, and it is getting all the information from the database correctly. :) Now my prob is just the displaying of events on their respective dates!

Comment: I see you just edited your question updating the events part. Here's the documentation for AJAX use: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ Try following such syntax with your configuration. I thought you were getting the data as a JSON feed, which is much easier to me, but go ahead with it. I tried looking for a way to fix the date issue, but by default you should get such configuration by default.

Comment: I have tried the syntax from the documentation, it's not working. When I try to do it, the calendar does not appear. This is for the retrieval using ajax. If I were to retrieve it by JSON (since i used json_encode) how would I do it? I have also tried retrieving events as JSON feed from the documentation and still, no luck. I also think that the date formats are not being read by fullcalendar, but I can output all database content via alert or the tooltip.

Comment: Just like PHP treats arrays, JavaScript treats JSON. So you can definitely get the parameters of a JSON feed as long as you set them correctly. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ If it doesn't work, may I get the URL to your project? Because I can check errors and stuff with Developer Tools on Safari.

Comment: Full calendar needs the date strings in a specific format, so you should use such format, in that point you are right. I would love to see the output from json_encode(). Can you dump the string so I can see what it has inside?

Comment: The time should be something like "2015-12-13T07:00:00" or "2015-12-13". You may try `events: [{ title: 'Meeting', start: '2015-12-12T10:30:00', end: '2015-12-12T12:30:00' }]` alone just to see if it displays correctly. If it does, it definitely is some data issue including, like you said, the time format.

Comment: @Zeke I am currently running my project on a localhost using xampp. Are there any other way to let you see the proj? I tried var_dump json from the php file but the calendar doesn't appear when i do so. Regardless, i have set alerts on the js file to output the database column contents. I tried the event you sent to me as a sample, and yes it is being read by the calendar :) I really appreciate you helping me, can we continue this conversation maybe on email?

Comment: I'm assuming this has less to do with the logic in your code and more to do with the expected input formatting for fullcalendar. Are you positive all the information you're passing to it is in the correct format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like your problem is that the JSON object returned by your URL has unrecognizable data for fullCalendar. So you'll have to fetch events like this:

```
events: base_url+'Calendar/view_tours',
```

And change the columns of your data base from `tour_id` to `id`, `tour_name` to `title`, `start_date` to `start` and `end_date` to `end`. This will create the correct JSON object.